Qt creator can not parse cmake version after update from Qt 6.5.3 to Qt 6.7.2
this issue has stocked to me for 2 days, I really want to fix this.
Backgound
I recently update Qt 6.5.3 to Qt 6.7.2 for Windows 10, there is a issue "error: The kit needs to define a CMake tool to parse this project." when I opened a project. Then I checked Edit>Preference>Kits, I see a warning says Cmake is unconfigured.

and I check Cmake Setting, It says cmake version is not parseable.

And there is no Cmake generator

What have I done
I tried to remove all components of Qt and install all over again using Qt maintenance tool, but nothing changes, I tried to install Qt creator Community 13.0.2 and Qt Creator 14.0.0-beta2 Community but nothing changes, I tried to Install Qt 6.5.3, Qt 6.6.3 and Qt 6.7.2 but nothing changes.
I checked my enviromment path, I think everything is fine.
Qt672 meas kits path for Qt 6.7.2, I alse have QT663 and qt653 for each specific version of Qt kit.

What is bizzared
I use Qt design studio for fun and I checked its preference setting, I found Qt design studio can parse Cmake version!!!!

And this show what I installed

This is so frustrating and sucks! I search every related web page, asked ChatGPT mang questions, But I really can not find a solution.
Any suggestion will be appreciated, Please help me!

I really can not find a solution, so I just install a virtual machine,  run QT in virtual machine, and it works fine.
